# How to databind Multiple Series to a Silverilght Toolkit Chart

Tags: silverlight, charts, toolkit

I am trying to use databinding to bind data to a Silverlight toolkit chart.
I will have one to many sets of series so cannot determine how many series i need before hand.
I also want to stick to a databinding model and not resort to programmatically adding these series as many other controls bind to this datasource.

I found an article on the web by Jeremiah Morrill that showed a solution for this very problem.

[Jeremiah's solution](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/351/Silverlight-Charts-Binding-multiple-Series.aspx)

Now this worked perfectly at first, until I tried to update my databinding's datasource values while the application was running, and this would not reflect. As if it was not subscribed to the PropertyChanged event.
I even bound the same data to a datagrid next to the chart, and the datagrid reacts as expected changing everytime my databinding's datasource values change.

In my ChartHelper from Jeremiah's solution, i have the following dependency property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SeriesSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SeriesSource", 
                                            typeof(IEnumerable), 
                                            typeof(ChartHelper),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(SeriesSourceChanged));
```

The SeriesSourceChanged event is called when my application starts up.
However, when my DataBinding's datasource values change, this is not called again.

So questions are as follows:

- How can I capture the PropertyChanged notification with this solution?
- Is there something I can add to the DependencyProperty above to capture this?
- Is it something i need to add to the chart or series to achieve this?

I have been racking my brain over this for several days, so any help or suggestions will be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: I have posted a CodePlex issue tracker with a sample solution outlining the problem

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=2973

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a solution to this problem and ended up using a chart control from [visifire](http://www.visifire.com/)

I found this much easier to customise but never found a neat way of using databinding to achieve this and ended up with a more programattic approach.

Answer (score 1):

The SeriesSource type should be ObservableCollection instead of IEnumerable. Then you do something like this:

```
private static void SeriesSourceChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var sender = o as YourType;
    var newCollection = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataSetViewModel>;
    if (newCollection != null)
    {
        newCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(sender.OnCollectionChanged);
    }
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```